# How to plot different results in Shadow with Scallion

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, torcheck, tor-cloud

I'm using Shadow to run a network simulation of Tor, with the scallion plug-in. When parsing and plotting the results, I only managed to retrieve the 'results-timing' graph. How do I parse and retrieve results to measure more performance characteristics, such as network throughput? Below are the steps I've taken to get the 'results-timing' graph:

```
$ cd shadow-git-clone/resource/scallion-hosts/
$ tar xaf tiny-m1.large.tar.xz
$ mv tiny-m1.large tor_test
$ cd tor_test
$ scallion
$ python /home/ubuntu/shadow-git-clone/contrib/analyze.py parse --output testing scallion.log
$ python contrib/analyze.py plot --title "Test 1 Tor" --data testing/ "testing"
```

Can I use the file-transfer plug-in alongside scallion? The `scallion --help` input does not show how to switch between measuring different types of performance characteristics.